# Java regex for Capital letters and numbers only

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to do a simple Regex in Java and it's failing for some reason. All I want to do is, validate whether a string contains upper case letters and/or numbers. So ABC1, 111 and ABC would be valid but abC1 would not be.

So I tried to do this:

```
    if (!e.getId().matches("[A-Z0-9]")) {
        throw new ValidationException(validationMessage);
    }
```

I made sure that e.getId() has ABC1 but it still throws the exception. I know it's something really small and silly but i'm unable to figure it out.

Comment: you're getting some good answers here, but none are explaining what your mistake is. The regex you have will only look to match one character, not every character in a string.

Answer (score 12):

Use `^[A-Z0-9]+$` as matching pattern. but `matches` method matches the whole string, `[A-Z0-9]+` is enough.

Answer (score 6):

You can try the following regular expression:

```
[\p{Digit}\p{Lu}]+
```

i.e.:

```java
if (!e.getId().matches("[\\p{Digit}\\p{Lu}]+")) {
    throw new ValidationException(validationMessage);
}
```